# How can I make the find-method work in this Laravel-code?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm a noob in this but I get different results from the similair code below

In this case $id=12

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id)->with(['comments'])->first();
    return $post;
}
```

This returns the post with id=1

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::where('id', $id)->with(['autor'])->first();
    return $post;
}
```

This returns the post with id=12

How can I make find method work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to know that `find($id)` is equivalent to `where('id', $id)->first()`. Both trigger the request call like for example the methods `get()`, `count()`, ...

So, once you call one of them, you get a result.

In your case, while on the model instance (`find` returned a model instance) , you called `->with(['comments'])` which did the same as `Post::query()->with(['comments'])`.

With a new query, `first()` did exactly what it is supposed to do, get the first entry `ID = 1`.

Basicly, you did run 2 query, and got the second query result.

For your first example, to make it work, call `find()` after `->with(['comments'])` without the first.

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::with(['comments'])->find($id);
    return $post;
}
```

This will either and instance of `Post` or `null`